# Redirect user to certain page after registration using Devise + confirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using Devise for user registration, and am using Confirmable to perform email validation.

After a user registers, I want to redirect them to a URL explaining that they need to check their email and click on the link sent. I am using Devise's `:authenticate_user!` method to ensure users log in before seeing site content.

Per [this file](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L2), it looks like I can define a `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)` and a `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` to control this redirect.

Here is my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:after_inactive_sign_up_path_for,     :after_sign_up_path_for]

def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
  confirm_path
end

def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(user)
  confirm_path
end

end
```

But it doesn't work. `confirm_path` is in my `static_pages` controller, which is accessible without signin as I have  `skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!` included

When a user registers, the `:authenticate_user!` helper kicks in and redirects to the login page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried overriding the registration controller like so :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/an/example/path'
  end
end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

Comment: I also had to override after_sign_up_path_for(resource)